# how to send a http request to my alexa skill and get a response from it?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Objective -
I created a basic Alexa skill using the Alexa hosted option, and I want to send an HTTP request to my Alexa back end in text or in JSON and get the response as a text without using an Alexa device.

question 1-
is this even possible with the Alexa hosted option

question 2 -
if it's possible will my user-id be Alexa skill messaging client id or the client id from my security profile?

my progress -
so I did a bit of research on this and found this page:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/send-a-message-request-to-a-skill.html

but I keep encountering two problems ie. when I try to make a post request.
1 - It says "type": "BAD_REQUEST", "message": "One or more parameters received are not in the correct format.", which I think is probably caused by this line -
MESSAGE='{"data":{ "sample message": "Sample Message"}, "expiresAfterSeconds": 60}'

2 - when I change my message to MESSAGE='{"data":{}' ie. an empty message.
it says
*{"type":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Invalid user id."}*

I tried both client id's ie. the one that my Alexa skill provides and the one which I created in my security profile but the outcome remains the same.
and
thus my question is this is even possible to do with the Alexa-hosted option.

Comment: And you're sure you have a good access token?

Comment: I used the curl command to get my access token as described on this page -   [link](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission-api/auth.html) and I also used `ask util generate-lwa-tokens` command according to this page [link](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html#get-lwa-credentials)

Comment: and I got my client-id, client secret from my skills permissions tab, and my security profile.

Comment: any luck on the progress?